# Devops CI/CD: Azure DataFactory - Pipeline and Link Service Parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to develop a release pipeline for Azure data Factory Ci/CD. I followed all the steps as suggested online by

A. Creating a release Pipeline

B. Adding Git as resource

C. Creating Task: Azure resource management deployment

I am stuck at `parameter` file. I have linked deployment task service to `adf_ branch` with template pointing to arm template and parameter file.

However I am not sure specify and replace `connection string` in parameter file. I have defined pipeline variables but cannot find way to use them in configuring deployment. Don't want to use Vault in the start. Simple replacing the values by variables is ok for me as I keep the linked services Name same across environments but I need to change data factory resource name.

For Example the connection for SQL is using password from vault, in which case what would be the `connection string`:

```
ConnectionString="Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().DBServer};Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=@{linkedService().DBUserName};password=?"
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: What is A? what is B? What is C?

Comment: Step A, Ste B and Step C in sequence, to creation of pipeline.